# How to update a Azure AD user?

Tags: azure-active-directory

I have successfully created a new user in Azure AD following [Create User reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/graph/api/user-post-users?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).

Now I want to update that very same user following [Update User reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/graph/api/user-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http). To keep things simple This is the JSon content I'm sending:

```
{
    "userType": "T"
}
```

The documentation tells me to send a PATCH request, but I always receive an HTTP Error 400 (*Bad request*). If I try sending a POST request I receive an HTTP Error 405 (*Method not allowed*).

The destination URL is `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/user-id`. 
The *user-id* is the one returned with the user details.

What am I missing?

### Update 1

Those are the permissions set to the application:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly how you update user (PATCH).

However the `userType` property cannot be `T`, from the docs you refer:

[image]

That property can only have one of the two distinct values: `Member` or `Guest`.

Of course, the `user-id` in path should the `id` property as returned by the get users operation.

I am pretty sure that if you use a normal REST client will be able to see the whole error message, which will be more meaningful.

If you still have issue - paste the exact error message.

Comment: Correct! My interpretation of that piece of text was the "Member" and "Guest" where just examples.

Comment: here I am with you. It is hard to undersrand that these are the only allowed values.